# SplitText removing line break?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I'm working with SplitText, the GSAP plugin, and whilst using it I noticed that it changed the;

```
<br>
```

tag in my element (comment out the first line in javascript to see the change). see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpWWJJ

I'm wondering why this change is being made and how I can revert it back to how it was before SplitText is applied. (how can I retain the line break?)

Thanks for any insight! John

Answer (score 1):

Split your paragraph into two separate paragraphs with different IDs and phase them in separately:

```
var descanima =  new SplitText("#descanim1");
var descanima2 = new SplitText("#descanim2");

var tl = new TimelineMax({});
tl.timeScale(1);
tl.staggerFrom(descanima.words, 1, { opacity: 0, x: 5, ease: Power1.easeOut}, 0.01)

tl.staggerFrom(descanima2.words, 1, { opacity: 0, x: 5, ease: Power1.easeOut}, 0.01)
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpqqNj

Comment: Thanks @AlliterativeAlice, I figured I'd do this, any idea what the reason behind it changing is?

Comment: @John107 I'm not sure but I'd imagine it just strips out all HTML tags before turning the words/letters into separate elements.